# using nested getElementById IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

So basically I was trying to use javascript to write a custom tag for all the different browsers, but IE 8-9 (haven't tested others) seems to not work correctly (what a surprise) (I am trying to make this feature compatible in Chrome FF IE 8- 10)

if you test this in different browser you will see that result 2 does not work in IE,
i could get it to work like in example one, however I would really prefer to use my custom tag name rather than an existing one.

**How can i make result 2 show up in IE and still use the tag name "drop"?**
Also I really want the html to stay the same and just make changes to the javascript,
Thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/9GXtH/

```
<select id='a' style='display:none'>
    <option id='b'>t1</option>
</select>

<drop id='c' style='display:none'>
    <option id='d'>t2</option>
</drop>

<div id='result'></div>

<div id='result2'></div>


var queue = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var options = queue.item(0).getElementsByTagName("option");

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = options.item(0).innerHTML;




var queue = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var options = queue.item(0).getElementsByTagName("option");

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "result: " +   options.item(0).innerHTML;


var queue = document.getElementsByTagName("drop");
var options = queue.item(0).getElementsByTagName("option");

document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = "result2: " +  options.item(0).innerHTML;
```

Comment: While you should not declare custom tags yourself, it should work if you call `document.createElement('drop');` somewhere in the source before the `drop` tag appears.

Comment: If you want new elements, you should use XHTML. See [Developing DTDs with defined and extended modules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/dtd_developing.html).

Comment: My ultimate goal is to use a "custom tag" so that when my page loads I run a javascript that transforms the "custom tag"  into a normal/typical tag like an input, I don't want to use a tag that is existing because that way I won't break anything.. Like how the select example works...

Comment: could someone provide an example of DTD?  If it would be too much work to provide an example I am not sure it is worth taking my time learning and building a DTD.

Comment: Why don't use use `data-*` attribute or `script` tags with `type='text/x-custom-data'` to store the information? If you create a custom tag `drop` and the next release of `html5` introduces a tag with this name in their specs having a different meaning then what you thought about, then you will have also a problem thats why you shouldn't do that.

Comment: after building this in a notepad I found that adding document.createElement did work!!!
Also That is a good suggestion to change it to data-drop.
Thanks t.niese!!!

Comment: still can't seem to get it to work in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7fTcm/  (in ie)

Comment: @Crushinator please check if it is just a iframe problem by opening your test case that way http://fiddle.jshell.net/7fTcm/show/ (loads it outside of the iframe) jsfiddle is not a good environment to test IE stuff when it is about bugs in older IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had something like this:

```
    <custom:drop id='c1' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option id='d1'>t2c1</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>
    <custom:drop id='c2' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option id='d2'>t2c2</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>
    <custom:drop id='c3' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option id='d3'>t2c3</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>
    <custom:drop id='c4' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option id='d4'>t2c4</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>
```

You could iterate through them in your script like this:

```
$("custom\\:drop custom\\:option").each(function(){
            console.log( $(this).html() );
        });
```

1

Comment: That's closer to what I am trying to do, but I really need a double loop:  here is my attempt sadly I could get to run in Chrome and FF but not IE: (I made it in notepad to test ie because jsfiddle doesn't seem to work at all on it)
http://jsfiddle.net/Eamwp/

Comment: Should be testing custom tags on a server, not something that's designed to expect normal html like jsfiddle.  And loading a page with a double click on a desktop is certainly not a good approach.  Are you using a server? jsFiddle is great but not well suited for outside the box thinking.

Comment: I'm using notepad and a browser (IE-9) trying to be compatible back to 8

Comment: most recent attempt that doesn't work in IE:
$("custom\\:drop").each(function()
{
    var s = "#"+($(this).context.id) + " custom\\:option";
    alert(s);
    $( s ).each(function(){
            alert( $(this).html() );
        });
    });

Comment: This worked however for Ie 7- 11 I added this code 
<html xmlns:custom="needed for custom elements">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">        
</head>
<body>
<script>
    // needed to make parse properly
    document.createElement('drop');
    document.createElement('option');
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Custom tags have a hard time because the browser has no idea what they are so they don't actually have any default properties or methods that can be relied on.  This is a page layout I used to make the custom tags in your example do what you need:

1. I used an xhtml1.1 Doctype Declaration.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">`

It actually works fine with `<!DOCTYPE html>` but the page won't validate with the W3C.  Custom tags are never going to validate because the validator has no idea what they are.

1. Added appropriate namespaces and an extra one for my custom DTD:  The url is irrelavent, it's just an identifier.

   `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
         xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:custom="http://www.custom_dtd.org/xhtml">`
2. Include charset and jQuery in the head.

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`
3. Rather than using getElementsByTagName on the custom tags, I used jQuery because they're custom tags and the DTD doesn't know what a custom tag has or doesn't have as far as methods or properties and they don't get any by default.  But jQuery finds them all quite well.  As I understand it, jQuery searches through the available tags and looks for a match (hence the regex looking escapes).
4. I've found this to work in Chrome, FF and IE8/9/10+, not IE7 but who cares?

Body contents:

```
    <select id='a' style='display:none'>
        <option id='b'>t1</option>
    </select>

    // our custom tags
    <custom:drop id='c' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option id='d'>t2</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>

    <div id='result'></div>

    <div id='result2'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var queue = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
        var options = queue.item(0).getElementsByTagName("option");
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = options.item(0).innerHTML;

        // have to escape the colon
        var queue = $("custom\\:drop");
        var options = queue.find("custom\\:option");

        document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = options.html();

    </script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it this way for multiple separate things?
In the end I really need to loop over a list of the "custom tag"

<custom:drop style='display:none'>
        <custom:option >t1</custom:option>
 <custom:option >t2</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>
<custom:drop id='a' style='display:none'>
        <custom:option >t3</custom:option>
 <custom:option >t4</custom:option>
    </custom:drop>

t1 & t2 would end up in say result1 and t3 & t4 would end up in result2